# MVC4 can not load jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page like:

```
@model PAP.Models.Account.LoginModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The bundles are configured like:

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

the code/page are working fine. but after I publish it to the production server (DEV pc is windows 7, server is windows 2012), jquery is not loaded. for this page, I am not using any layout.

where and how should I fix this!!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you published in Release mode, the bundler is looking for a .min version. Did you upload both versions?

Comment: @TiesonT., That's not correct. By default the bundler will create a .min version if one does not exist.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think we're both a little off. The bundler isn't actually creating a .min version if it's missing, it's simply using the non-minified version in the concatenated and minified file generated for the bundle. If that's what you meant, then I yield the point.

Comment: @TiesonT., I didn't word that too well did I! I suspect OP issue is that the no jquery file(s) have been copied/published to the production server

Comment: yes, for your question, I did upload the .min version js files

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question:

I used fiddler to track the http request and find out the form authentication block the access to "bundles" folder.

what I did is to add the bundles folder to allow anonymous access. this works! but I have other similar projects without this issue. Still can not figure out a real reason for this. Any body has any ideas?

Here is part of my config:

```
  <location path="pub">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="bundles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30" />
      </authentication>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Did you add an AuthorizeAttribute to your FilterConfig? That would make it force authorization on every single request, including those for assets in the /Content folder. Otherwise, make sure your /Content folder is excluded from the routing mechanism by adding this to RouteConfig: `routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "content" });`